# Making dropdown list in kivy. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_widget'

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, kivy

I already used available topics to improve my code but still something doesn't work. Running code gives me `Attribute error:'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_widget'`.

```
class Datownik(DropDown):
    pass

class ZleceniaPojedyncze(Screen):
    dzienButton = ObjectProperty(None)
    miesiacButton = ObjectProperty(None)
    top_layout = ObjectProperty(Screen)   <------ changed
    rokButton = ObjectProperty(None)
    dd_btn = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ZleceniaPojedyncze, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.drop_down = Datownik()

        dropdown = DropDown()
        notes = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']
        for note in notes:

            btn = Button(text='bcda', size_hint_y=None, height=30)
            btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: dropdown.select(btn.text))
            dropdown.add_widget(btn)

        mainbutton = Button(text='abcd')
        print("yay")

        mainbutton.bind(on_release=dropdown.open(self)) <--added self param.

        dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

        self.top_layout.add_widget(mainbutton)
```

And here is coresponding kv file:

```
<Datownik>:
Button:
    text: 'B1'
    height: 44
    on_release: root.select('item1')
Button:
    text: 'B2'
    height: 44
    on_release: root.select('item1')
Button:
    text: 'B3'
    height: 44
    on_release: root.select('item1')

<ZleceniaPojedyncze>:
name: 'zp'
dzienButton: dzienButtonID
dd_btn: btn_ddID    
top_layout: topLayoutID
GridLayout:
    id: topLayoutID
    height: self.minimum_height
    row_force_default: 'true'
    row_default_height: 30
    col_force_default: 'true'
    col_default_width: 70
    cols: 4
    padding: 70
    Button:
        id: dzienButtonID
        text: 'day'
    Button:
        id: btn_ddID
        text: 'month'
        on_release: root.drop_down.open(self)
    Button:
        text: 'year'
    Button:
        text: 'back'
        on_release: app.root.current = 'mm'
```

I only want to make it work with one button for now, just dropdown menu, and later i will try to figure out what part do what to configure this menu for my needs, but i guess i mixed things up somehow and cant proceed. Any1 to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `top_layout` is declared as `ObjectProperty(None)` and then you're trying to add widgets to it when it is None: `self.top_layout.add_widget(mainbutton)`.

Comment: Ok, so i changed the object property for screen and other stuff, all that came up to my head. When setted as Screen property it gives back TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 required positional argument: 'widget'. What property should i set?

Comment: First off, I don't have any way to know what you changed. Secondly, `TypeError: add_widget() missing 1 argument` means you can't just do `layout.add_widget()` with no widget. Instead do `layout.add_widget(button)`, for example.

Comment: First off wanna say i aprreciate ur help. Thats very kind. After some while i realized what was the problem with widget missing argument, i left the property as Screen, but after changes there is another error. DropDownException: Cannot open a dropdown list on a hidden widget . Appareantly "top_widget" is not really top widget. This must be a consequence of using screen manager, any way to fix it?

Comment: What is the `top_widget` you are talking about?

Comment: My bad. Its supossed to be 'top_layout', not a 'top_widget'. I think this error comes up because screen where dropdown is placed, is 3rd in a row in a screen manager, but thats just a long shot guess.